# Проверка значений ячеек html по вертикали и горизонтали php

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос простой, как средствами php выполнять проверку по вертикали и горизонтали в единичном шаге (т.е. по 1 ячейки с верху, с низу, с права и лева) в таблице html которую сам скрипт и создает.  К примеру:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
set_time_limit(30);

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

echo "<table>";
    echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($i=1; $i <= 25; $i++) {

            echo "<td>1<td/>"; //тут должны быть некие вычисления вычисления

            if(($i % 5 == 0) && !($i == 25)) {
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";


$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Время выполнения скрипта: '.ceil($time).' сек.';
?>
```

Получается таблица 5 на 5 c 1ми, и предположим каждую ячейку нужно проверять по вертикале и горизонтали.

Comment: Никак, у тебя просто длинная строка в примере;
Вообще, нарисуй на листочке таблицу и уже сам поймешь как ее обходить

Comment: Да я то же хотел это сказать, у тебя там не таблица рисуется а строка

Comment: На что проверять? И в чём разница, проверять по вертикале и горизонтали?

Comment: я использую open server, а не sandbox, на странице выходят таблица пять на пять, есть вопрос как предположим значение ячейке по середине проверить с соседними